# How to check if nsmutablearray contains integer value

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Am getting the following dat from array through json,StatusArray is

```
(
    (
    5
),
    (
    4
),
    (
    3
),
    (
    5
),
    (
    1
),
    (
    1
)
```

)

Now i need to compare these values with integer values and adding it to the tableview cell label. my code is,

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:data

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
 NSLog(@"%@", json);
totalArray =[json objectForKey:@"Files"];
 NSLog(@"%@", totalArray);
fileIdArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
loanNumberArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
borrowerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
adressArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
statusArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
ordersArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


for (int i=0; i<[[json objectForKey:@"Files"] count]; i++)
{
    [fileIdArray addObject:[[totalArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"FileID"]];
    [loanNumberArray addObject:[[totalArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"LoanDetails"]];
    [borrowerArray addObject:[[totalArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Borrower"]];
    [adressArray addObject:[[totalArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"PropertyAddress"]];
    [ordersArray addObject:[[totalArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Orders"]];
}
statusArray = [ordersArray valueForKey:@"Status"];

if ([statusArray containsObject:@"1"]) 
{
    UILabel *statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];
    statusLabel.text=@"New";
    NSString *label=statusLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",label);
}
else if([statusArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2]])
{
    UILabel *statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];
    statusLabel.text=@"Pending";
    NSString *label=statusLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",label);
}
else if([statusArray containsObject:@"4"])
{
    UILabel *statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];
    statusLabel.text=@"Accepted";
    NSString *label=statusLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",label);
}
else if([statusArray containsObject:@"5"])
{
    UILabel *statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];
    statusLabel.text=@"Completed";
    NSString *label=statusLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",label);
}
```

Am unable to find the label text and its not going to any condition.whats wrong with my code Please correct me.

Thanks

Comment: can you post the code how you initialize `statusArray`?

Comment: Could you please show json from which the status array is created?

Comment: statusArray = [ordersArray valueForKey:@"Status"];

Comment: for (int i=0; i<[[json objectForKey:@"Files"] count]; i++)
    {
        [fileIdArray addObject:[[totalArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"FileID"]];
        [loanNumberArray addObject:[[totalArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"LoanDetails"]];
        [borrowerArray addObject:[[totalArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Borrower"]];
        [adressArray addObject:[[totalArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"PropertyAddress"]];
        [ordersArray addObject:[[totalArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Orders"]];
    }
    statusArray = [ordersArray valueForKey:@"Status"];

Comment: If your response is array means try like this [statusArray firstObject].

Comment: Can you please tell me more clear [statusArray firstObject] means i can get only the first object?

Comment: like this you can check [statusArray objectAtIndex:index]

Comment: @user3040319 please update your question with code rather than posting it in the comments, that unreadable :)

Comment: I think he means that your objects seem in fact to all be arrays with one (integer) object in each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
   for (int x=0; x<[StatusArray count]; x++) {

    NSMutableArray *array = [StatusArray objectAtIndex:x];

     NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:0]];

    if ([string isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        UILabel *statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];
        statusLabel.text=@"New";
        NSString *label=statusLabel.text;
        NSLog(@"%@",label);
    }
    else if([string isEqualToString:@"2"])
    {
        UILabel *statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];
        statusLabel.text=@"Pending";
        NSString *label=statusLabel.text;
        NSLog(@"%@",label);
    }
    else if([string isEqualToString:@"4"])
    {
        UILabel *statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];
        statusLabel.text=@"Accepted";
        NSString *label=statusLabel.text;
        NSLog(@"%@",label);
    }
    else if([string isEqualToString:@"5"])
    {
        UILabel *statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];
        statusLabel.text=@"Completed";
        NSString *label=statusLabel.text;
        NSLog(@"%@",label);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives me this error,

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9aa1cbe1a0'

Comment: NSString *string = [[StatusArray objectAtIndex:x]stringValue] try this

Comment: it throws me error again, Any help?
reason: '-[__NSArrayI stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8c386e5b80'

Comment: please see updated answer this will work properly now.
the problem was your status array is collection of arrays and we were comparing it objects as string thats why it was giving crashes

Comment: my answer , i have updated it use this this will work perfectly

Comment: Sorry to say, its again crashing,
[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000053

Comment: ok. no problem..
replace  NSString *string =[array objectAtIndex:0]; 
this with
  
 NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:0]];

Comment: Wow, this is the most complicated answer possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your `statusArray` is an array of arrays. And you are trying to compare array with string.

Try this one:

```
UILabel *statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];
if ([statusArray containsObject:@[@1]])
{
    statusLabel.text=@"New";
    NSString *label=statusLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",label);
}
else if([statusArray containsObject:@[@2]])
{
    statusLabel.text=@"Pending";
    NSString *label=statusLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",label);
}
else if([statusArray containsObject:@[@3])
{
    statusLabel.text=@"Accepted";
    NSString *label=statusLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",label);
}
else if([statusArray containsObject:@[@4])
{
    statusLabel.text=@"Completed";
    NSString *label=statusLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",label);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but its going to any condition.

Comment: Maybe your values are not strings? Try to change them to NSNumbers. Code in answer updated